# Is it possible to write-protect an NFC tag using the Web NFC API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, nfc, ndef, google-chrome-flags

I'm trying to use the three basic NFC functions in Google Chrome (Web NFC API, navigator.nfc).

I know it's possible to read and write NDEF messages on tags. What I did not find out yet is how to protect the written data on the tag from being overwritten. Is this possible?

Comment: What exactly are you up to? Do you want to write-protect the data once written to the tag?

Comment: Yes Michael! Is this possible with web nfc?

Answer (score 3):

The Web NFC API specification explicitly mentions write-protection of NFC tags as one of the highest-priority threats (see [section 7.2](https://cdn.staticaly.com/gh/w3c/web-nfc/2a645519f730d8d44f911c654695db8f5e3e993e/index.html#threats)):

> Protecting existing NFC tags from being overwritten by malicious web pages.

However, in its current state, the Web NFC API itself does *not* provide a way to set write-protection for a tag.